# Why is waiting for a thread to terminate called "joining"?

Tags: multithreading

Be it Java, C#, C++, posix threads, and so on. All threading libraries name the method that waits for a thread to terminate `join`. Why is this the case?

The wording sounds counterintuitive to me, because "joining" someone in doing some task means doing the task together/helping the person with the task. It does not mean "sleep until the other person did the task, then wake up and go on".

So where does the concept of "joining" originate from?

Comment: If you combine two physical threads into one, you're joining them.

Comment: 'Cause it's the opposite of 'forking'?